# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath pushes data loaded last from NSArray no matter which row is selected

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView which is populated with some parsed JSON twitter data. The intent is to have the user select the a row, and have the data passed to a modalViewController, which in this case is a map displaying coordinate and annotation information.

In the debug console I can see the data loaded into each visible UITableViewCell, plus the first one off screen (last loaded).  When I run the app, and attempt to select a row, no matter which row I select, the data from the last loaded cell is always the data passed to the modalViewController.

I have logged to ensure the correct row is selected (it is) but no matter which row is selected, the last data loaded is always the data that is pushed.

First the Data Source Methods

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
    NSUInteger count = [self.results count];
    return count > 0 ? count : 1;
    }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *ResultCellIdentifier = @"ResultCell";
    static NSString *LoadCellIdentifier = @"LoadingCell";

    NSUInteger count = [self.results count];

    if ((count == 0) && (indexPath.row == 0)) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LoadCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                      reuseIdentifier:LoadCellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    }

    if (self.connection) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading...";
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"Not available";
    }
    return cell;
}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ResultCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                  reuseIdentifier:ResultCellIdentifier];
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];;
}

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"medicaltag.png"];
cell.imageView.image = image;

// Begin UITableCell Data Formatting
NSDictionary *tweet = [self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString* tweetText = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];

if ([tweetText rangeOfString:@" *** "].location !=NSNotFound) {

    NSArray *textItems = [tweetText componentsSeparatedByString:@" *** "];

    NSLog(@"%@", textItems);   

    callAddress = [textItems objectAtIndex:0];
    callAddress = [callAddress stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" , " withString:@", "];
    callType = [textItems objectAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"%@", callType);
    NSLog(@"%@", callAddress);

    NSString *latitude = [textItems objectAtIndex:2];
    NSString *latStringPt1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *latStringPt2 = [[NSString alloc] init];

    NSString *longitude = [textItems objectAtIndex:3];
    longitude = [longitude stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"- " withString:@"-"];
    NSString *lonStringPt1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
    NSString *lonStringPt2 = [[NSString alloc] init];

    int latStringLen = [latitude length];
    int lonStringLen = [longitude length];

    NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", latStringLen);

    latStringPt1 = [latitude substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,latStringLen-6)];
    latStringPt2 = [latitude substringFromIndex:latStringLen-6];
    combinedLatString = [latStringPt1 stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    combinedLatString = [combinedLatString stringByAppendingString:latStringPt2];

    lonStringPt1 = [longitude substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,lonStringLen-6)];
    lonStringPt2 = [longitude substringFromIndex:lonStringLen-6];
    combinedLonString = [lonStringPt1 stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    combinedLonString = [combinedLonString stringByAppendingString:lonStringPt2];

    NSLog(@"%@", combinedLatString);
    NSLog(@"%@", combinedLonString);
    }

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", callAddress];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", callType];
cell.detailTextLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
return cell;
}
```

Now the Delegate Method

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods*

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

NSLog(@"%i", row);

CallMapViewController *mapVC = [[CallMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallMapViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
mapVC.annotCallType = callType;
mapVC.annotCallAddress = callAddress;

NSLog(@"%@", mapVC.annotCallType);
NSLog(@"%@", mapVC.annotCallAddress);

NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *lat = [f numberFromString:combinedLatString];
NSNumber *lon = [f numberFromString:combinedLonString];

mapVC.annotLatCoord = lat;
mapVC.annotLonCoord = lon;

NSLog(@"%@", lat);

NSLog(@"%@", lon);

NSLog(@"%@", callType);

NSLog(@"%@", callAddress);


[self presentModalViewController:mapVC animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have your tweet data stored in your viewController's property `results`, so you just need to grab the data from there and parse it again (as Daryl Teo mentions) in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* tweetText = [[self.results objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"text"];
    if ([tweetText rangeOfString:@" *** "].location != NSNotFound) {

        NSArray *textItems = [tweetText componentsSeparatedByString:@" *** "];

        CallMapViewController *mapVC = [[CallMapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CallMapViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
        mapVC.callAddress = [[textItems objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" , " withString:@", "];
        mapVC.callType = [textItems objectAtIndex:1];

        [self presentModalViewController:mapVC animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for pointing out the need to re-parse the data in my delegate method! This solution worked perfectly... thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You get [indexPath row] but you don't use it.

And you've got "callType" and "callAddress" which aren't within the scope of the delegate method. They exist as instance variables of the viewController, and you set their values as you're creating the cells. That's why their values are always the values of the last cell.

You need to store the data in memory, so that you can reference it when you get the row from indexPath.

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *tweetText = [tweetsStorageArray objectAtIndex: row];

/* Parse Tweet Text again */
```

You can either store tweets as text, or create a storage class and store that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You take the `[indexPath row];` but you don't chose your data base on that.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in your delegate `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath ()` you are only accessing the selected row variable for NSLog messages.

You would probably need to access the cell using `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]` and its contents using `callType = cell.detailTextLabel.text;`and `callAddress = cell.textLabel.text;`